# Which part of an angular velocity vector is its direction?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, vectors, conventions, angular-velocity

I am assuming that an angular velocity vector only has two direction: positive for counterclockwise and negative for clockwise.

Just to make sure that I have the right interpretation.

Newton's 1st law states:

> An object remains in a state of uniform rotational motion unless acted upon by a net torque. ("In a straight line" is taken out)

This means that the speed of the angular velocity vector is constant. However, even without an net torque, the direction will change. **how?**

Edit. I just googled Newton's 1st Law. It only says uniform motion in a straight line. Does it mean the object can travel back and forth along the line?

Comment: Understand the vector of angular momentum better, here: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/219890/ . Newton's 1st applies to pure rotation as it does to pure translation.

Comment: @Gert, how to we measure the angle between the force and position vectors? Sin270 will be -1.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. So $\sin 270^\circ=-1$, so what?

Comment: @Gert, my book did not limit the range of theta to [0, 180]. (Formula: t=rFsintheta)

Comment: It doesn't have to: an angle is an angle is an angle, period.

Comment: But the direction is different. The sign of toque is different.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31955/discussion-between-gert-and-doeser).

Answer (score 1):

By uniform motion in a straight line, the law refers to both its magnitude and direction. You can't go back and forth without a force.